# How to set qml output directory for windeployqt

Tags: qt, qml, windeployqt

I would like to use `windeployqt.exe` to deploy all required dll, plugins and qmls. 
`windeployqt.exe` provides options to copy dll to the directory specified by `--libdir`, copy plugins to `--plugindir`.
But option `--qmldir` has a different purpose. It used for scanning for qml dependencies. By default qml files and binaries are copied to the application folder.

Is there any way to specify directory `--qml-output-dir` where qml files will be placed?

Comment: Not from what I can see.

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

In windeployqt this is not possible.

But in an alternative [cqtdeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer) application i planed to add this [feature](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/issues/145).

---

**Updated**

@DarkSidds We have added the required functionality support to our utility. You can download and try [here](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases).

**Using:**

```
 %cqtdeployer% -bin path/to/bin.exe -qmake /path/to/qmake.exe -qmlDir path/to/your/qmlSource/Folder -qmlOut folderNameOfQmlOutputDir
```

-qmlOut - set the path to qml dependencies relative to the target directory

**For example:**

You are deploying the application to "/target/path". And your "qmlOut" is equal to "myQmlDep" then all qml dependencies are stored in "/target/path/ myQmlDep".

For more info see [readme](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/blob/master/doc/Options.md) of utility

---

**Updated**

Version of cqtdeployer with this futures has ben [released](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases/tag/1.3.0)